# How to set initial capacity to a SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I'm looking into code optimization of a project of mine and I was wondering how can I set an initial capacity to a SortedDictionary. I know that I can do it to a List and a Dictionary pretty easily in the constructor. But how can I do it to a SortedDictionary?

I thought about doing it like the code below, but I'm not sure if that works and how I could check it, once Dictionary has no capacity property (or has it?).

```
int capacity = 1000;

SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> exampleSortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no need to specify initial capacity for `SortedDictionary<K, V>`.

Please note, that `Dictionary<K, V>` is a *hash table* that's why the initial capacity (say, `1000` "rows") is quite reasonable. Unlike `Dictionary<K, V>`, `SortedDictionary<K, V>` is a *red-black tree* for which capacity has no meaning.

Comment: So I guess my best choice is to work with Dictionaries and If I need a SortedDictionary at some moment, I just convert it to that specific need, right? Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Lucas Ferreira: You can work with *interface* `IDictionary<K, V>` which allows to *choose* implementaion with `Dictionary<K, V>` or `SortedDictionary<K, V>` without business logic changing

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitry Bychenko, I'll take a look into IDictionary. Have a great day!